# The abstract schema type is unknown

Tags: jpa, junit

I'm using Spring 3.2.3, JPA 2.1, JUnit 4.11.  I'm trying to run a junit test and I keep getting the abstract schema type is unknown error.  Here is my entity (truncated for space, it has all the getters and setters):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WEB_PROFILES")
public class TestWebProfile implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Transient
private String forward;

@Column(name = "ACCESS_FLAG")
private String accessFlag;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "ACCESS_FLAG_UPD_DATE")
private Date accessFlagUpdDate;

@Column(name = "ACCESS_RESET_INTERVAL")
private BigDecimal accessResetInterval;

@Column(name = "ACCOUNT_TYPE")
private String accountType;

@Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
private String createdBy;

@Column(name = "E_MAIL")
private String eMail;

@Column(name = "FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS")
private BigDecimal failedLoginAttempts;

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "FROI_ACCESS_APPROVE_DENY_DATE")
private Date froiAccessApproveDenyDate;

@Column(name = "FROI_ACCESS_APPROVED_FLAG")
private String froiAccessApprovedFlag;

@Column(name = "FROI_ACCESS_REQUESTED")
private String froiAccessRequested;

@Column(name = "FROI_APPROVED_BY")
private String froiApprovedBy;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "FROI_CONFIRM_EMAIL_SENT_DATE")
private Date froiConfirmEmailSentDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "FROI_LETTER_SENT_DATE")
private Date froiLetterSentDate;

@Column(name = "LAST_LOGON_ADDR")
private String lastLogonAddr;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "LAST_LOGON_DATE")
private Date lastLogonDate;

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY")
private String lastUpdatedBy;

@Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY_NAME")
private String lastUpdatedByName;

@Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY_SU_ID")
private BigDecimal lastUpdatedBySuId;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "MAIL_SENT_DATE")
private Date mailSentDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "MAINT_DATE")
private Date maintDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "NEW_PIN_REQ_DATE")
private Date newPinReqDate;

@Column(name = "PASSWORD")
private String password;

@Transient
private String newPassword;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "PASSWORD_UPD_DATE")
private Date passwordUpdDate;

@Column(name = "PHONE")
private String phone;

@Column(name = "PIN")
private String pin;

@Column(name = "POLICY_NUM")
private BigDecimal policyNo;

@Column(name = "PROFILE_CLASS_CODE")
private String profileClassCode;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "PROFILE_REQ_DATE")
private Date profileReqDate;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "PROFILE_UPDATE_DATE")
private Date profileUpdateDate;

@Column(name = "REMOTE_ADDR")
private String remoteAddr;

@Column(name = "SESSIONID")
private String sessionid;

@Column(name = "SUBSCRIBER_FLAG")
private String subscriberFlag;

@Column(name = "USER_ID")
private BigDecimal userId;

@Id
@Column(name = "USER_NO")
private BigDecimal userNo;

@Column(name = "USERNAME")
private String username;
```

My JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testGetWebProfileByUsername() {

    TestWebProfile wp = sso.getWebProfile("MARLENE");
    System.out.println("name :" + wp.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("last name :" + wp.getLastName());
}
```

My DAO implementation:

```
@Override
    public TestWebProfile getWebProfile(String username) {
        String sqlString = "select w from TestWebProfile w where w.username =:username";

        return (TestWebProfile) getEntityManager()
                .createQuery(sqlString, TestWebProfile.class)
                .setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult();
    }
```

After Googling for the past hour, the only culprit I found that seem to make sense was not having the @Id and @Column annotations, but I have those on the userNo variable.  Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In my case I was still referencing some old `javax.*` libraries instead of `jakarta.*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at this. It gives some suggesstion for the same case http://java.dzone.com/tips/the-nasty-jpa-unknown-abstract

Comment: Thanks @MGPJ, I saw this post.  After looking at it again, I figured out the problem.  We are using Java configuration for Spring and on the entityManager bean, I needed to add an additional package to be scanned.  Once I did that, it worked just fine.

Comment: The link seems to have been removed. It no longer works

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Java SE you have to add the fully qualified name of your entity class in persistence.xml, like so

```
<persistence-unit ...>
    <class>your.custom.package.TestWebProfile</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Omitting the package part may lead to your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding inside your persistence-unit tag  as follows:

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

For some reason in my case although I was listing all the classes inside my persistence unit using fully qualified names, eclipseLink didn't recognize them. Once added that line, it just works.
I was using:

1. Java SE 8
2. Maven Project
3. EclipseLink (Local not an application server)
4. Netbeans